# Using a subquery with parameters in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I am trying to run a query that uses a subquery to represent a column of the result set.

```
select id_column1, id_column2, id_column3,
(select column4 from table2 where id in (id_column1, id_column2, id_column3)
order by id desc
limit 1) as column4
from table1
join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
join table3 on table2.id = table2.id
where clause...
```

the sqlalchemy equivalent I have is

```
order_state = aliased(Table1)
po_state = aliased(Table1)
proof_state = aliased(Table1)

subq = meta.Session.query(Table2.exception_message).\
  filter(Table2.entity_id.in_([Table3.id, Table4.id, Table5.id])).\
  order_by(Table2.id.desc()).\
  limit(1).label('exception')

query = meta.Session.query(
  Table3.po_number, Table4.id.label('po_id'), Order.id.label('order_id'),\
  Table5.id.label('proof_id'), order_state.description.label('order_state'),\
  po_state.description.label('po_state'), proof_state.description.label('proof_state'),
  Table3.order_placement_date, subq).\
  outerjoin(Table4, Table3.id == Table4.order_id).\
  outerjoin(Table5, Table4.id == Table5.po_id).\
  outerjoin(order_state, Table3.state_diagram_state_id == order_state.id).\
  outerjoin(po_state, Table4.state_diagram_state_id == po_state.id).\
  outerjoin(proof_state, Table5.state_diagram_state_id == proof_state.id).\
  filter(Table3.is_placed != 0).\
  filter(not_(Table3.po_number.contains('%-%'))).\
  filter(not_(Table3.state_diagram_state_id.in_(Table1.NONE_ORDER_EXCEPTIONS))).\
  filter(or_(Table3.state_diagram_state_id.in_(Table1.ORDER_EXCEPTIONS),\
    Table4.state_diagram_state_id.in_(Table1.PO_EXCEPTIONS),\
    Table5.state_diagram_state_id.in_(Table1.PROOF_EXCEPTIONS)))
```

How do you use a subquery in sql alchemy that uses the columns you are querying as parameters to that filter?

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

(edited based on the referenced sqlfiddle)

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

sql = """
CREATE TABLE Table1
     (
     id int primary key,
     type varchar(20),
     details varchar(30)
    );

CREATE TABLE Table2
     (
     id int primary key,
     type varchar(20),
     details varchar(30)
    );

CREATE TABLE Table3
     (
     id int primary key,
     type varchar(20),
     details varchar(30)
    );

CREATE TABLE Table4
     (
     id int primary key,
     entity_id int,
     type varchar(20),
     details varchar(30)
    );

INSERT INTO Table1 (type, details) values ('data1', 'details of data1');

INSERT INTO Table2 (type, details) values ('data2', 'details of data2');

INSERT INTO Table3 (type, details) values ('data3', 'details of data3');

UPDATE Table2 SET id = 2 where id = 1;
UPDATE Table3 SET id = 3 where id = 1;

INSERT INTO Table4 (entity_id, type, details) values (1, 'exception', 'err 1');
INSERT INTO Table4 (entity_id, type, details) values (2, 'exception2', 'err 2');
INSERT INTO Table4 (entity_id, type, details) values (3, 'exception3', 'err 3');

"""

e = create_engine("sqlite://", echo=True)

for stmt in sql.split(";"):
    e.execute(stmt.strip())

from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import DeferredReflection
Base = declarative_base(cls=DeferredReflection)

class Table1(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table1'

class Table2(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table2'

class Table3(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table3'

class Table4(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'Table4'

Base.prepare(e)

from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
s = Session(e)

subq = s.query(Table4.type).filter(Table4.entity_id.in_([Table1.id, Table2.id, Table3.id]))
q = s.query(
        Table1.type,
        Table2.type,
        Table3.type,
        subq.label('table4type')
    ).join(Table2, Table1.id == Table2.id).join(Table3, Table2.id == Table3.id)
print q.all()
```

Comment: maybe to make it a little clearer, here is the full query I am trying to run using the suggestions that you had.

Comment: I get the following error too if this helps InvalidRequestError('in() function accepts either a list of non-selectable values, or a selectable: <sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute object at 0x30e8450>',)

Comment: whoops, I forgot the brackets, added those.  try it that way.

Comment: I did modify the query before your comment and already included the brackets. I still get error. BTW I am on 0.7 of sqlalchemy if that helps!

Comment: feel free to post a simple test case i can run (it's unlikely it would need all those joins)

Comment: this a link to sqlfiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8a9100/3 it should have a very simple raw sql snippet, Not sure how to give you a working example for sqlalchemy. thanks for looking into this.